# How to connect php 5.4.4 with microsoft sql server 2008 R2 in windows Xp?

Tags: php, sql-server, windows-xp, connection

How to connect php 5.4.4 with microsoft sql server 2008 R2 in windows Xp?
i have installed xampp 1.8.0 with apache2.4 and php 5.4.4 embedded in it.
i have installed microsoft sql server 2008 R2.
i have download and configure php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll and php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll.
but when i execute sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connection) it says,"This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client.".
the problem is Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client is not compatible with Windows Xp. Any suggestion for my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using version 2.0 or version 3.0 of php_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll?

Have you got quotes around your extension dir? e.g.:

```
extension_dir="C:\Program Files\PHP\ext"
```

For driver version 3.0 you need:

```
A 32-bit version of PHP
A web server (e.g. IIS or Apache) configured to launch PHP using FastCGI.
ODBC driver "SQL Server Native Client 11.0" ( SQL Server 2012 Native Client )
```

- or * for driver version 2.0 you need:

  A 32-bit version of PHP
  A web server (e.g. IIS or Apache) configured to launch PHP using FastCGI.
  ODBC driver "SQL Server Native Client 10.0" ( SQL Server 2008 Native Client )

For further assistance, You may have a look [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc296170%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: i use SQLSRV30 and add extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll to my php.ini.

Comment: in the link you give, i see that i need to use the 2.0 driver version, but the 2.0 version can't handle the php 5.4.